# Making DataGriView Row(S) unselectable

Tags: c#

I have a DataGridView with 3 rows.

I am adding a fourth row programmatically.

Is there any way to prevent the user from selecting the three rows after I add the fourth row.

Thanks a ton everyone

Comment: You don't want the users to select it or you don't want them to edit the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataGridView1.Rows[0].ReadOnly = true;
DataGridView1.Rows[1].ReadOnly = true;
DataGridView1.Rows[2].ReadOnly = true;
```

This will make sure that the users cannot edit the data on the first 3 rows.

Or something like...

On the Cell_Click event,

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.RowIndex == 0) || (e.RowIndex == 1) || (e.RowIndex == 2))
            {

                dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want them selecting and acting on the row you added?  If so, you don't need the grid for that, you can assume whatever row they're on is the one you want them to be on, even if they're not.